What is B supposed to turn into in this 8-bit adder?

I understand that it takes 4A and subtracts it from B but the two appended 1s that are added to B make it difficult for me to understand. What am I subtracting from 2A? 1B1?
I couldn't find any examples with similar inputs either. The answer key says it's supposed to be 2B but I do not think they are similar in any way, unless there is something I am missing?

I see in the picture the usual addition of two bytes, taking into account Cin = 1 carry. Then the addition of the result with a value of 00000000 or 11111111, depending on the value of Cout carry. What is the ultimate goal?

@KonstantinMakarov Well the question has asked for the value of Z. But I can't understand what B is supposed to be with those two 1s.

Maybe this example with specific values will clarify the situation?
A is multiplied by 4: 4A.
B is inverted 63 - B, multiplied by 2 and added 128 + 1 = 129: 2(63 - B) + 129 = 255 - 2B. If we consider these 1s as part of an inversion, that will lead to the same result: 255 – 2B.
The first adder result taking into account Cin: 255 – 2B + 4A + 1 = 256 - 2B + 4A. Since it is 8-bit, that leaves 4A - 2B.
The second adder subtracts 1 from the result if it is negative.

